# Is Azkaban a good choice for Scheduler for big data solutions?

Tags: bigdata, batch-processing, scheduling, oozie, azkaban

We came across choice to work on Scheduler named Azkaban with good UI benefits and dependencies resolution.

Read through the document https://azkaban.github.io/azkaban/docs/latest/ and started using.
Struggle to mark it stable for long run of scheduled jobs.
So, what is the azkaban stability point of view in terms of:

1. any challenges faces?
2. critical issues?
3. Response from community support for Azkaban?